# Current user filter does not work for "migrated" users

Tags: sharepoint-designer, caml

we are using a Sharepoint list in which employees can capture their expenses. We are using the [Me] filter on "Author" column to let the user only see his own entries.

Due to organizational reasons we had to create a new user for each employee, which means that we have "John Doe" with ID 123 and a second (the new one) "John Doe" with ID 456.

Of course User 123 captured a lot of entries which User 456 should see. User 123 won't be used anymore. Therefore I wrote a short RPA script to update the "Author" column in the Sharepoint list and replace the old "John Doe" through the new one. When opening the list and clicking on "Doe, John" the profile of the new user (456) opens - everything looks right at this point. Nevertheless, if the new John Doe is logging in he can't see these entries that were initially captured by the old user.

Any idea how to solve this? When I look at the CAML query (in Sharepoint Designer) which controls the view I cannot see any reason why the new user shouldn't see the entries where the Author column is also referencing this new user.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try removing the user from the site and add back in. I think the old account's permission still exists in SharePoint

Comment: Are you talking about just to remove user permissions for the site or remove the whole user? I have tested to delete the old user completely from the Sharepoint but it doesn't have any effect...

Comment: What is the SharePoint Version? Is the library or list has "Item-Level" permission? Maybe you can first check the permission of the new user on the list/library item to see if the user has permission or not. When you're talking User ID, where that comes from? Are these from hidden 'User Information List"?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is SharePoint 2013. I didn't know about this "Item-Level" permission thing but this might be the reason indeed. The new user has no permission for the old entries but only for those he captured himself. Any hint how to fix this in a smooth way for all items?

Comment: My understanding is that we have a hierarchy like SITE -> LIST -> ITEM. By now, permissions are ITEM based which is not necessary - it is even not necessary to control the permissions on LIST level but it should be sufficient to define SITE level permissions. If I reactivate the inheritance on LIST level (such that LIST permissions are derived from SITE permissions), will the ITEM permissions also be disabled?

Comment: Basically, need to loop through all the items in the list and grant each item permission to the user who is in [Author] column, which you have made changes to. Here is a link how you can accomplish this with PowerShell script: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/03/break-inheritance-set-item-level-list-permission-powershell.html

Comment: Yes, if you don't need item-level permission then you can go to the permission setting of the list and "Delete unique permissions" for the list to inherit permission from its parent like site and site collection. It all depends on your business requirements.

Comment: Obviously this isn't the case. I have reactivated the permission inheritance for the list such that the list gets its permissions from the site. Neverthless, the list items have their own permissions as before - as these are around 4k elements I could not change them manually...